# Spring boot + (JPA) - Category hierarchy - recursively traverse

Tags: java, spring, jpa, recursion

I have Catalog Entity -

```
public class Category {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column
private String categoryName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Category parent;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Category> children = new ArrayList<Category>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
private Set<Product>
```

And records in the table :

```
id,  category_name,   parent_id
'1', 'HOME',            NULL
'2', 'Category 1',       '1'
'3', 'Category 2',       '1'
'4', 'Sub-Category 1',   '2'
'5', 'Sub-Category 1 2', '2'
```

And some methods in the controller (in my case but the questions is principle)

```
List<Category> categoryList = categoryRepository.findAll();

    for (Category cat : cateList) {
        recursiveTree(cat);
    }



public void recursiveTree(Category cat) {
        System.out.println(cat.getCategoryName());
        if (cat.getChildren().size() > 0) {
            for (Category c : cat.getChildren()) {
                recursiveTree(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i run this, in the console i get -

```
HOME
Category 1
Sub-Category 1
Sub-Category 1 2
Category 2
Category 1
Sub-Category 1
Sub-Category 1 2
Category 2
Sub-Category 1
Sub-Category 1 2
```

How can i modify the recursion, so i can get the proper order of categories and subcategories? I can't figure out why i get some duplicates data

Comment: because `getChildren()` doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you help me ?

Comment: I'd like to but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get duplicate data because you are fetching *all* Categories from the database with `List<Category> categoryList = categoryRepository.findAll();`

This list contains HOME, Category 1, Category 2, ...

Since for each item of this list you call the `recursiveTree` method in your main loop, you will print the tree for HOME (which will thus print all its children), you will also call `recursiveTree` for Category 1, printing that category and its children again, and so forth.

If you want each category printed only once, only look up the root categories (HOME and any others without parent you may have) and call `recursiveTree` for those. For example:

```
List<Category> rootCategoryList = categoryRepository.findByParentIsNull();
for (Category cat : rootCategoryList) {
    recursiveTree(cat);
}
```

Comment: You are genius !! I I still can't understand how it is working .. :) explain a bit more ? How i get only parents with null and in the same i get the sub-directories (which don't have null value for parent). 
Do you have some tutorial how to implement this in a thymeleaf view :)

Comment: Whell, when calling `cat.getChildren()` in your `recursiveTree` method, the children will be retrieved from the database so they can be returned. Note that if you want to do something similar in thymeleaf, you should iterate over your categories first (that is: call a method similar to `recursiveTree` but which doesn't print) since by default the database connection is no longer available to you during view rendering. To render in thymeleaf, you can use fragments - see for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032838/how-to-render-menu-using-thymeleaf-recursively)

Answer (score 0):

To show the category tree in thymeleaf, this code works perfectly

```
<div th:fragment="submenu">
        <ul>
            <li th:each="cat : ${categories}">
            <span th:text="${cat.categoryName}"></span>
                <div th:with="categories = ${cat.children}" th:include="admin/fragments/info :: submenu"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```