# Java Hibernate json infinite recursion with self referencing class 2

Tags: java, jackson

**Details about database:** folder_Meta_Data has fields id,parentFolderId in which id nothing but folderid acts like primary key and parentFolderId refereces to id.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "folder_Meta_Data")
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id",scope=FolderMetaData.class)
public class FolderMetaData implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq-gen", initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "seq-gen")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "projectId", nullable = false)
    private Long projectId;
    @Column(name = "mgId", nullable = false)
    private Long mgId;
    @Column(name = "folderRoot", length = 50)
    private String folderRoot;
    @Column(name = "folderExtention", length = 50)
    private String folderExtention;
    @Column(name = "folderName", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String folderName;
    @Column(name = "createdBy", nullable = false)
    private Long createdBy;
    @Column(name = "createdTime", nullable = false)
    private Date createdTime;
    @Column(name = "versionOCC")
    private Long versionOCC;
    @Column(name = "subProjId", nullable = false)
    private Long subProjId;
    @Column(name = "modifiedBy")
    private Long modifiedBy;
    @Column(name = "modifiedTime", length = 50)
    private Date modifiedTime;
    @Column(name = "parentFolderId")
    private Long parentFolderId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentFolderId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    // @JsonIgnore
    // child role
    private FolderMetaData folder;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "folder")
    // parent role
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<FolderMetaData> folderList;

    // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

**JSON Tree response:**

```
The response i am getting is  as below
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "projectId": 125,
        "mgId": 34512,
        "folderRoot": null,
        "folderExtention": null,
        "folderName": "XY1",
        "createdBy": 12,
        "createdTime": "2018-03-16",
        "versionOCC": null,
        "subProjId": 561565,
        "modifiedBy": null,
        "modifiedTime": null,
        "parentFolderId": null,
        "folderList": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "projectId": 125,
        "mgId": 34512,
        "folderRoot": null,
        "folderExtention": null,
        "folderName": "XY2",
        "createdBy": 12,
        "createdTime": "2018-03-16",
        "versionOCC": null,
        "subProjId": 561565,
        "modifiedBy": null,
        "modifiedTime": null,
        "parentFolderId": null,
        "folderList": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "projectId": 125,
                "mgId": 34512,
                "folderRoot": null,
                "folderExtention": null,
                "folderName": "XY2",
                "createdBy": 12,
                "createdTime": "2018-03-16",
                "versionOCC": null,
                "subProjId": 561565,
                "modifiedBy": null,
                "modifiedTime": null,
                "parentFolderId": 2,
                "folderList": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "projectId": 125,
                        "mgId": 34512,
                        "folderRoot": null,
                        "folderExtention": null,
                        "folderName": "XY2",
                        "createdBy": 12,
                        "createdTime": "2018-03-16",
                        "versionOCC": null,
                        "subProjId": 561565,
                        "modifiedBy": null,
                        "modifiedTime": null,
                        "parentFolderId": 3,
                        "folderList": [
                            {
                                "id": 5,
                                "projectId": 125,
                                "mgId": 34512,
                                "folderRoot": null,
                                "folderExtention": null,
                                "folderName": "XY2",
                                "createdBy": 12,
                                "createdTime": "2018-03-16",
                                "versionOCC": null,
                                "subProjId": 561565,
                                "modifiedBy": null,
                                "modifiedTime": null,
                                "parentFolderId": 4,
                                "folderList": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    3,
    4,
    5
]
```

In the service class method I am calling below method to retrieve all records. As it is Jackson api, all fetched records are populated into list as parent and children relation. Records getting as json tree.

```
    List<FolderMetaData> list=folderRepository.findAll();
```

**Problem is:**
    after using @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference in FolderMetaData pojo.

```
The tree is coming correctly. but in the bottom of this json array response, I am getting dirty data which are ids of subtrees. if anyone help me to fix this issue, that would be great.
```

**like below**

```
,
    3,
    4,
    5
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is lombok `@Data` which generate `toString`, `equals` and `hascode` methods referencing your self referenced property. This is generating stackoverflow error which is not not related to serialisation but root cause is the same (self reference). Please use lombok [Exclude](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) as described in documentation or use `@Getter @Setter` and implemented this methods by yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but I checked it is not working

Answer (score 0):

the problem is cause you get all data from database,
you can check here [Spring boot + (JPA) - Category hierarchy - recursively traverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553925/spring-boot-jpa-category-hierarchy-recursively-traverse/46554042), he is have the same problem