# Comment tree, making replies to reply to show up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need to implement comment tree but can't get replies to reply to work.

Comment.java

```
...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String content;

    @ManyToOne
    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne
    private Comment parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Comment> children = new ArrayList<Comment>();
...
```

PostController.java

```
model.addAttribute("comments", commentRepository.findAllCommentsByPostIdAndParentIsNull(id));
```

post.html

```
<th:block th:each="comment : ${comments}">
<p th:text="${comment.content}">comment</p>

<th:block th:each="child : ${comment.children}">
<div class="child">
  <p th:text="${child.content}">comment</p>
</div>
</th:block>
</th:block>
```

comment database

```
ID | CONTENT | PARENT_ID | POST_ID
1    text1         null        1
2    text2          1          1
3    text3          2          1
4    text4         null        1
```

Output i want

```
text1
  text2
    text3
text4
```

output i get

```
text1
 text2
text4
```

Basically replies to replies don't show up.

How do i go about getting the output i want?

Comment: You could use some kind of recursion, take a look at this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032838/how-to-render-menu-using-thymeleaf-recursively]

Comment: so you want to get all comments based on `post_id`? even `PARENT_ID` is null?

Comment: Thanks Alex R, managed it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the following

```
<th:block th:each="comment : ${comments}">
  <p th:text="${comment.content}">comment</p>
  <div th:fragment="f_call(comment)" 
      th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(comment.children)}" >
      <div th:each="child : ${comment.children}" th:inline="text">
          [[${child.content}]]
          <div th:replace="this::f_call(${child})"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</th:block>
```

Comment: Previous comment was unrelated to this, it works, thanks.